# Where is the zone actually configured for an interface in firewalld?

Tags: firewalld, ansible

I'm using ansible for adding zones to my firewall on a Centos machine.  Didn't realize until it (almost) too late, that I'm not getting the IN_Internal interface working, it's all going to public, which is the default defined by firewalld.conf.

This is my internal.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<zone>
  <short>Internal</short>
  <description>For use on internal networks. You mostly trust the other computers on the networks to not harm your computer. Only selected incoming connections are accepted.</description>
  <interface name="eth0"/>
  <service name="ipp-client"/>
  <service name="mdns"/>
  <service name="dhcpv6-client"/>
  <service name="ssh"/>  
</zone>
```

doesn't seem like it's getting used at all.

because, for whatever reason I wind up with:

```
 Chain IN_internal (0 references)
      2   120 IN_public  all  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]
```

Can't see why that's what's happening there.

When I do `firewall-cmd --zone=internal --change-interface=eth0` and it works (even after I reload the firewall), but it's exactly the same XML

Since I'm deploying my settings with ansible, and not running firewall-cmd on the machine, I'd like to know what firewall-cmd is doing behind the scenes so that I can push out those configs.

Answer (score 2):

`man 5 firewalld.zones` claims that

> **How to set or change a zone for a connection?**
>
> The zone is stored into the ifcfg of the connection with `ZONE=option`. If the option is missing or empty, the default zone
>      set in firewalld is used.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out. I grepped all of /etc/ for `zone`, `eth0`, `internal`, didn't see anything.  I think the --permanent option isn't working in my version of centos because ifcfg-eth0 definitely doesn't have a zone in it.  Guessing this would be unset if I restarted the interface.